# PHP - sort function with 'SORT_LOCALE_STRING' return incorrect result

Tags: php, mysql, collation

I have some MySQL records in type **VARCHAR**, collation is **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**:

```
Tiếng Việt Nam
Tiếng Hoa Kỳ
Tiếng Anh
Tiếng Nhật
Tiếng Hàn Quốc
Tiếng Thái Lan
```

Then, I use PHP to sort them by Alphabet order:

```
$languages = [
        'Tiếng Việt Nam',
        'Tiếng Hoa Kỳ',
        'Tiếng Anh',
        'Tiếng Nhật',
        'Tiếng Hàn Quốc',
        'Tiếng Thái Lan',
    ];
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'vi');
sort($languages, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```

Result when calling `var_dump($languages)` like that:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string 'Tiếng Anh' (length=11)
  1 => string 'Tiếng Hoa Kỳ' (length=16)
  2 => string 'Tiếng Nhật' (length=14)
  3 => string 'Tiếng Thái Lan' (length=17)
  4 => string 'Tiếng Việt Nam' (length=18)
  5 => string 'Tiếng Hàn Quốc' (length=22)
```

Something incorrect with order of **'Tiếng Hàn Quốc'**, result should be like so:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string 'Tiếng Anh' (length=11)
  1 => string 'Tiếng Hàn Quốc' (length=19)
  2 => string 'Tiếng Hoa Kỳ' (length=16)
  3 => string 'Tiếng Nhật' (length=14)
  4 => string 'Tiếng Thái Lan' (length=17)
  5 => string 'Tiếng Việt Nam' (length=18)
```

Then, I replaced existed **'Tiếng Hàn Quốc'** with other one (also **'Tiếng Hàn Quốc'**) by typing directly to MySQL (using HeidiSQL). Finally, I got expected result.

I think the different thing here:

```
string 'Tiếng Hàn Quốc'(length=22)
string 'Tiếng Hàn Quốc'(length=19)
```

**The questions are:**
What is root of problem here?
How can I resolve this problem in MySql or PHP code to get expected result without find and replace all incorrect values in MySQL?

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest to parse problem string by ord() function symbol by symbol and compare with normal string. If codes not be matching, replace it to right symbols

Comment: The discrepancy is typically due to the fact that some characters like e.g. `à` are visually identical whether they are a single unicode character or a combined character with accent. The fact that `Tiếng Việt Nam` drops to last might indicate that the problem is `ế` counting as a different character in that case.

Comment: @A.Mikhailov thank for your suggestion, but I think that way is hard to do or I lack understanding your idea. Can you be more specific with some sample codes?

Comment: @apokryfos: Thank you. I understood what you have indicated. Is there any way to parse character from one type to other type?
**a single unicode character** to **a combined character with accent** and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  You need this collation:  `utf8mb4_vietnamese_ci`.

Long answer:  The strings have different UTF-8 hex representations:

```
Tiếng Hàn Quốc (length=20)  54 69 C3AA CC81 6E 67 48 61 CC80 6E 51 75 C3B4 CC81 63
Tiếng Hàn Quốc (length=17)  54 69  E1BABF   6E 67 48  C3A0   6E 51 75  E1BB91   63
```

There is, however, a potential problem:

```
C3AA        234=x00EA  [ê]    L  LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX
CC81        769=x0301  [́]  NSM  COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
6E          110=x006E  [n]    L  LATIN SMALL LETTER N

E1BABF     7871=x1EBF  [ế]    L  LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX AND ACUTE
6E          110=x006E  [n]    L  LATIN SMALL LETTER N
```

In the first string, ê is rendered via a single utf8 character (hex C3AA) and acute-n is rendered via a pair of utf8 characters -- a non-spacing accent and the letter n.

In the first string, the acute accent is part of the letter e.  I don't know anything about Vietnamese encoding in utf8, but this sounds 'wrong' if the acute should really be on the letter n.

But, in any case, those two strings compare equal with collation utf8mb4_vietnamese_ci (or utf8_vietnamese_ci).